# How to find the child project of a parent project which is passed in the 'WHERE' clause and also, to find the duplicate objects

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I am finding this a bit weird, though I do know SQL, but i have never written such queries in my career.

My requirement is like this:

I have a table named PSPROJECTITEM, which have these columns:

```
PROJECTNAME OBJECTTYPE  OBJECTID1   OBJECTVALUE1    OBJECTID2   OBJECTVALUE2    OBJECTID3   OBJECTVALUE3    OBJECTID4   OBJECTVALUE4
```

I need to write a query which has to fetch the child rows or the child PROJECTNAME of a PARENT PROJECTNAME, which i will pass in the query.

```
SELECT PROJECTNAME AS PARENTPROJECT, COUNT(*) AS PARENTOBJECTCOUNT FROM PSPROJECTITEM where PROJECTNAME = 'AAAA_JOB_KJ'
```

My goal is to find the child projects of this PROJECT which i have passed here, and also , to get the count of the other values, which i think is the total number of row count, as AAAA_JOB_KJ have total count of 199 in the table.

I want to get child project, the count, and also, the number of duplicate count, i.e, how many parent and child objects are similar, i mean, the number of objects which are similar between the parent and the child. Hope this is clear now.

Here is the sample data:

```
Parent Project Name Parent Project Count    Child Project           Child Count  Similar Object Count
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_AUTOFILL_SP1         11           3
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_CSRIDHAR_0518        3            1
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_DUP_TERM_FACT        2            1
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_E000316038_HCM_789   2            1
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_E000368318_PROJ      3        2
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_HCM_1104_SPD_1028    7        1
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_HCM_889_SPD_871      11       1
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_JOB_CHANGE           5            1
AAAA_JOB_KJ     199                 AZ_MGR_TERMIN       31           1
AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                 AZ_PAYROLL_VALIDATIONS  19       4
AAAA_JOB_KJ     199                 AZ_Q4AUTOCHG        22           2
AAAA_JOB_KJ     199                 AZ_Q4AUTOCHG_ENHCMT     8            2
AAAA_JOB_KJ     199                 AZ_Q4_BCKUP         225         130
```

Please note that the count of child objects can be more than the parent project.

Also, note that there are two kind of projects, one is peoplesoft delivered and others are custom project. I think a general query will be able to handle this.

Kindly let me know if any other modification is needed, as I know that this is very complex, and also, this needs little bit of editing, i tried it, but could not find on how to to do this, I am sorry for this

Database in use is ORACLE.

All are in the same table.

**Edited by moderator to add:**

The parent project is in the `PSPROJECTITEM`. Suppose i have query,

```
SELECT PROJECTNAME AS PARENTPROJECT, COUNT(*) AS PARENTOBJECTCOUNT 
FROM PSPROJECTITEM where PROJECTNAME = 'AAAA_JOB_KJ'
```

I need a query to fetch the child projects of this project which i have passed in the where clause, the count of the child projects, and also, the duplicate count.

** Addition **

The query below is able to do most of the intended.

Now, a bit of modification is needed:

My sample data is like this:

Parent Project Name Parent Project Count    Child Project           Child Count  Similar Object Count
    AAAA_JOB_KJ         199                     AZ_AUTOFILL_SP1         11           3

but the query output is this:

Parent Project Name Parent Project Count    Child Project           Child Count  Similar Object Count
AAAA_JOB_KJ 5   AZ_AUTOFILL_SP1 5

5 is wrong, 199 is the desired out, because the count of AAAA_JOB_KJ is 199 in the table, same for AZ_AUTOFILL_SP1.

Also, need to find the similar objects amongst these table, and display there count.

I think either an inner join or cross join will do to display the count.

Comment: This isn't clear - your sample data has different columns that your list of fields.

Comment: Hi folks, Thanks for the help, but this is a bit urgent. Also, feel free to ask any question from me, or any modification, I will be there to help. This is indeed complex.

Comment: Please, create a [sqlfiddle link here](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and I think, we can better to understand and faster answer your question

Comment: @egrunin: hi, thanks for the help, oh, okay, the sample data or the headers is in the file actually, i mean, they are title.

Comment: @Fabio: I am really sorry, as of now, I am short of time to create the sqlfiddle link, kindly ask me any question, and i will definitely help you :)

Comment: @egrunin: Sorry, i think, i have written COLUMNS as FIELDS. The objecttype, objectid1, etc are the columns of the PSPROJECTITEM, and parentproject etc are the file headers. I will modify that

Comment: Ahh, is your sample **data** (which implies input data) actually your sample **output**?

Comment: @egrunin: Yes, it is, that is the output. Kindly let me know that how shall i provide you data, so that it becomes simple to you. Thanks :)

Comment: All we need to know is: which column of `PSPROJECTITEM` tells us which is the parent project? Or is that in some other table?

Comment: @egrunin: Thanks for the help. The parent project is in the PSPROJECTITEM. Suppose i have query, SELECT PROJECTNAME AS PARENTPROJECT, COUNT(*) AS PARENTOBJECTCOUNT  FROM PSPROJECTITEM where PROJECTNAME = 'AAAA_JOB_KJ', I need a query to fetch the child projects of this project which i have passed in the where clause, the count of the child projects, and also, the duplicate count. Thanks

Comment: This is still completely unclear: **which column connects parents and children?** In other words, when I (a human) look at a project name in `PSPROJECTITEM`, how do I know which are its children?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31701/discussion-between-egrunin-and-vamosrafa)

Comment: @egrunin: Actually, we have list of the PROJECTNAME which are consdiered as the PARENT PROJECT. I have used one projectname in the query here, that's the parent project. I need to find the child projects of this project name, which is parent. And also, need to match the objects, to find the similar number of objects between the parent project and the child project. The column in use is PROJECTNAME, and the other columns to be mapped are OBJECTTYPE, OBJECTID1, etc, which is mentioned above. Thanks. I know this is very complex, and I have missed out on many things. I am really sorry for this.

Comment: [Here sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3540), but you need to check if data structure are correct and add your sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most of the answer, as we determined in the interactive chat:

```
SELECT A.projectName as PARENT,COUNT(A.PROJECTNAME) AS PARENTPROJECTCOUNT, 
    B.ProjectName as CHILD, COUNT(B.PROJECTNAME) AS CHILDPROJECT from psprojectitem 
a INNER JOIN psProjectItem B 
ON a.objecttype = b.objecttype 
AND a.objectid1 =b.objectid1 
AND a.objectvalue1 = b.objectvalue1 
AND a.objectid2 = b.objectid2 
AND a.objectvalue2 = b.objectvalue2 
AND a.objectid3 = b.objectid3 
AND a.objectvalue3 = b.objectvalue3 
AND a.objectid4 = b.objectid4 
AND a.objectvalue4 = b.objectvalue4 
WHERE A.projectname in 
(SELECT ProjectName from psProjectDefn WHERE lastupdoprid <> 'pplsoft') 
AND a.projectname <> B.projectName 
and A.PROJECTNAME = 'AAAA_JOB_KJ' 
ORDER BY B.PROJECTNAME
```

Comment: This was indeed great from you, god bless you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve most of the requirement:

```
SELECT A.projectName as PARENT,
(select COUNT(*) from PSPROJECTITEM WHERE PROJECTNAME = A.PROJECTNAME) parentprojecount, 
B.ProjectName as CHILD, 
(select COUNT(*) from PSPROJECTITEM WHERE PROJECTNAME = B.PROJECTNAME) CHILDPROJECT from psprojectitem 
a  INNER JOIN psProjectItem  B 
ON a.objecttype = b.objecttype 
   AND a.objectid1 =b.objectid1 
   AND a.objectvalue1 = b.objectvalue1 
   AND a.objectid2 = b.objectid2 
   AND a.objectvalue2 = b.objectvalue2 
   AND a.objectid3 = b.objectid3 
   AND a.objectvalue3 = b.objectvalue3 
   AND a.objectid4 = b.objectid4 
   AND a.objectvalue4 = b.objectvalue4
WHERE A.projectname in 
(SELECT ProjectName from psProjectDefn WHERE lastupdoprid <> 'pplsoft') 
AND a.projectname <> B.projectName
and A.PROJECTNAME = 'AAAA_JOB_KJ'

group by A.PROJECTNAME,B.PROJECTNAME
ORDER BY B.PROJECTNAME
```

The output generated is:

**AAAA_JOB_KJ   199 AZ_AUTOFILL_SP1 11.**

The only thing which is pending is finding duplicate rows amongst the child and parent, i.e. what are the counts of the common objects of child and parent.

Help on this will be great, Thanks.